# "love to look at and appreciate" or "appreciate and look at"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I love to look at and appreciate mountain sceneries.

I have a doubt that the phrase "love to" can be used 
with "appreciate". It sound strange to me.
Would it be suitable to rephrase the sentence into
" I appreciate and love to look at mountain sceneries?"
Please explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Those two sentences mean different things.

First off, I think we need to examine your use of "sceneries". If you mean scenery as in a painted background that one might use in a theater production, then it can take a plural form.

If however you meant scenery in the sense of a picturesque view of some place or other, then it does not have a plural form, and can be used as-is to refer to the plural. This is the more common form, so I'll use it in explaining my reply to your question.

> I love to look at and appreciate mountain scenery.

This one means that you are very fond of *the act of looking at and admiring* mountain scenes.

> I appreciate and love to look at mountain scenery.

This one means that you admire mountain scenery and also love looking at them.

They are both technically correct, but which one you should use depends on what thoughts you are trying to get across.